# Converting .fla or .swf to gif (Command prompt / Action script / Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash, gif

I'm currently looking for a solution to convert any .fla or .swf file into a .gif without using the basic "File > Export to ..." (This is for a pretty large amount of files)

I can use any of the following languages : Action Script, Flex or even the windows command prompt.
I already had a look at http://www.swftools.org/about.html but there's only a GIF2SWF, and not a SWF2GIF.

Anyway, if anyone know a possible way to do this, thanks in advance !

Comment: I wouldn't expect this is possible.  What is your purpose?  Do you just want each library graphic to convert to a gif?  Or is there something else going on?

Comment: I'm trying to do that to "automatize" the creation of gif file, for instance I'll just get a really big amount of .fla / .swf file, I just want to parse a folder and convert all this into .gif (For later integration or ...) http://www.adshareit.com/flash-to-video-command-line.html is approx. what I'm looking for but it's 1k5$ the license :-/

Answer (score 0):

Could you be interested into this one http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Programming/Visual_Basic_Components_A-G/SWF_To_Image.html ? Anyway, if you query the search engines with "batch convert SWF to GIF" you'll probably find more.